# Highcharts Chrome 71 leak

Tags: highcharts

When you update from Chrome 70 to 71, addPoint seems to break. There is something in that method that is causing the page to halt and CPU use to skyrocket.
Does not happen on Chrome 70 but does on 71.

http://jsfiddle.net/6xkfvbnt/3/
Clock "Add Points" and watch your Chrome task manager.

Anyone else seeing this?

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: []
    }]
});

$('#button').click(function () {
    var datapts = [];
    for(var x=0; x<613645; x++) {
      datapts.push([1417410061000+x, x]);
    }
    for (var i=0; i < datapts.length; i += 1) {
      chart.series[0].addPoint(datapts[i], false);
    }
    chart.redraw();
});
```

Comment: Happens to me  in Version 70.0.3538.102 (Official Build) (64-bit). I don't find this particularly strange since 613645 points are added and rendered. Works slightly better if the boost module is included (http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/gkpx37yo/)

Comment: It takes forever though and used to be quite quick.  The rendering for me took under 2 seconds in Chrome 70 and now takes over a minute.  It is still quick if you use setData.  Only happens with addPoint

Comment: You are right, I have now tested in Version 71.0.3578.80 (Official Build) (64-bit). It now takes well over a minute. I see you have created a bug report for this as well: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9645, hopefully that should lead to this being fixed shortly.

Answer (score 0):

We have concluded this is an error in Chrome 71 rather than highcharts.  With a simple jsfiddle using Array splice, this happens even without Highcharts.
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9645

If you are having this issue, use setData and not addPoint as setData does not use Array.prototype.splice.